# How do I get rid of a white block behind <p> text that is covering the background image of the <div> block

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner programmer with HTML/CSS/PHP. I tried to program a basic site for a University Project, but the paragraph and header Image I set have a white background behind them covering the background image I set for the specific .

The website in its current state looks like this:
http://prntscr.com/by2jcp
http://prntscr.com/by2kut

The HTML and CSS Code used was:

```css
body {background: #ffffff; margin: 0; padding: 0;} 
a {color: #2b2bf6;}           
#container {width: inherit; margin: 0; padding: 0; background: #990000;}           
#header {width: inherit;  height: 200px;  margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; background-image: url(http://www.conversantmedia.com/dotomi/images/design.png); border-bottom: 3px solid black }
#header h{font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;font-size: 28px ;}
h1{text-align: center;}
#sidebar {width: 200px; height: 1250px;  margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 2; float: left; background: #0093FF; background-image: url(http://s357.photobucket.com/user/ev1ln1ghtmar3/media/blue-flame-smoky-design-1.jpg.html)}           
#content {width: 85%; height: 50%; margin 0; padding: 0; border: 0; float: left; background-image: url(http://feelgrafix.com/data_images/out/15/890731-snowy-wallpaper.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    
}        
#content p {font-family: Arial; font-size: 130%; margin-left: 10px; text-align: inherit; color: black;}
#content h1 {font-family: Arial;}
#footer {width: inherit;  height: 70px;  margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; background: #05126B; clear:both;}
#footer p{ color: white; margin-left: 10px;}
#tab t{font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px;}   
#sidebar button {background-color: #377AFF; width: 180px; margin-left: 10px;height: 40px; color: aliceblue; font-size: 20px}           
#sidebar h3 {text-align: center; color: azure;border-bottom: 3px solid aliceblue; font-size: 24px;}
#header img {height: 100px; width: 250px; margin: inherit}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black; font-size: 25px; background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>METIS</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"> </div>
<div id="header"><h><h1><img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/wr14av.png"></h1></h></div>

<div id="sidebar"><h3>DELIVERABLES</h3> <br />
    <a href="Repos.HTML"><button type="button">Deliverable 0</button><p></p>
    <a href="Deliverable1.html"><button type="button">Deliverable 1</button><p></p>
    <a href="Deliverable2.html"><button type="button">Deliverable 2</button><p></p>
    <a href="Deliverable3.html"><button type="button">Deliverable 3</button><p></p>
    <a href="Deliverable4.html"><button type="button">Deliverable 4</button><p></p>
    <a href="Deliverable5.html"><button type="button">Deliverable 5</button><p></p>
    <a href="Deliverable6.html"><button type="button">Deliverable 6</button><p></p>
    <a href="Deliverable7.html"><button type="button">Deliverable 7</button><p></p>
    <a href="Deliverable8.html"><button type="button">Deliverable 8</button><p></p>
    <a href="Deliverable9.html"><button type="button">Deliverable 9</button>
</div>

<div id="content"> 
    <h1><img src="http://i68.tinypic.com/2hhlu2a.png"></h1>
    <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>Student Number</th>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Prahiel</td>
    <td>Last Name</td> 
    <td>Student Number</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Heinrich</td>
    <td>Last Name</td> 
    <td>Student Number</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rahul</td>
    <td>Last Name</td> 
    <td>Student Number</td>
  </tr>
        <tr>
    <td>Otlile</td>
    <td>Last Name</td> 
    <td>Student Number</td>
  </tr>
        <tr>
    <td>Arthur</td>
    <td>Last Name</td> 
    <td>Student Number</td>
  </tr>
</table>
    <h1><img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/2hq49kx.png"></h1>
    <p>
        We are a group of individuals currently in our final year of study (Informatics). We have come together with the single purpose of perfection, to deliver a quality service in our systems that seek to both enhance and simplify life; opening doors to greater efficiency and innovation.</p>
    <br />
    <h1><img src="http://i66.tinypic.com/dpb5z5.png"></h1>
    <p>
        After the initial meeting with the client and inspection of premises, and business operations certain issues came to the fore. Firstly Aroma has paper a based loyalty system, namely a paper card that accrues stamps with every purchase. The problems arising here is the discontent among consumers should the card be lost (or forgotten) and the lack of accuracy of confirming the total purchases made by the said consumer and there is also the cost in terms of printing (paper and ink). Secondly no current stock system exists, Aroma tends to make an unnecessary loss in profit as inaccurate stock quantities are ordered, this stock is then given to staff at the end of the business day if the stock is of a perishable nature. This continuous over-stocking needs to be addressed, especially in the current business environment, where profitability is of utmost importance.</p>
    <p>
    Lastly on the problems list: the premises is currently small and limited for space, especially during peak hours (Mornings and evenings). Customer frustration runs high during these times and many are prompted to leave, and should frustration not be the crux then it would be the matter of time: being late for other pressing matters.
    </p>
    
    
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <p>this is the footer for the work</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to know if there is a reasoning behind it happening and if there is a way to fix the problem. I have searched through StackOverflow and I couldn't find a solution that worked. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This `<h>` is not a valid element.

Answer (score 0):

That would be the background color of the table

```
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

or the body

```
body {
background: #ffffff;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Removing the background colour of the body and the table or setting them to transparent did not fix the problem.

Comment: Then you will have to make a demo that **actually** show the problem, You code does not do that.

Comment: I'll gladly make a demo, but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: You're most of the way there,,,use the Stack Snippet already in your question. Just link in proper images.

Comment: I edited the above snippet to include images. I hope that works.

Comment: Sure looks like the body background to me.

Comment: Setting the height of the Container to a static px size seemed to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can change iframe like this.

```html
<iframe id="image-iframe" class="resizable" src="http://prntscr.com/image.html" style="border: 0px; height: 450px; width: 971px; background-color: transparent;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: Would I replace the <div> tag with the <iframe> tag?

Comment: you can try with and without my friend

Answer (score 0):

Try adding background-size:cover; to #sidebar and #content divs that might help to get desired output.